# C# converting from visio to an image

Tags: c#, image, visio

Is it possible to convert a .vdx document to a .png or jpg programmaticaly through C#? It is preferable if this can be done for free.

Comment: I should clarify. I already have a .vdx (visio document) that has been created through C# and now i want to convert it to an image programatically. I have already encountered aspose but it is somewhat overpriced so want to avoid going down that path.

Comment: Of course it's possible. Either you must write a tool to do it yourself (too broad of a question for Stack Overflow) or you must use an existing tool to do it (and asking for recommendations isn't allowed on SO).

Answer (score 0):

I had a project where I needed to draw a lot of UML diagrams using Visio. The diagrams had to be included in various project outputs, such as a design report and a project wiki, requiring export from Visio to PNG format whenever a change was made to any diagram.

Tried using *vsd2svg* in combination with *ImageMagick*, but it produced PNGs with missing fonts. I ended up writing a macro in Visio that does the work. [Here's the breakdown](http://www.independent-software.com/automated-conversion-of-many-visio-drawings-to-png/).

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at using http://vdxtosvg.sourceforge.net/ to convert your .vdx to a .svg file and then https://svg.codeplex.com/ to convert to a .png.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413348/how-to-convert-multiple-visio-file-vsd-to-png) has an answer that shows how to do it from VBA.  Perhaps it could be used as the basis for some C# code.

Comment: Cheers, yeah think it's going to be a case of using .svg as an intermediary point. Appears there is nothing that already exists in order to go straight to an image.

Comment: Apart from that, note that vdx format was discontinued by Microsoft.

Comment: Agreed, here is the MS link for the announcement changing from *.vdx to •.vsdx: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767103.aspx#vis15_WhatsNew_NewFF